# POST checked and unchecked checkboxes with html php

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, html-table

I'm having hard time to figure it out how to insert the checked box-es or unchecked into the database with php.

I tried many many different ways but none is working, I think I'm very close but can't figure it out the problem.
Btw I work with Javascript and never worked with PHP except this time.

index.html

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         @import "demo_page.css";
         @import "header.ccss";
         @import "demo_table.css";
         @import "select.dataTables.min.css";
         @import "jquery.dataTables.min.css";
      </style>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="RowGroupingWithFixedColumn.js"></script>
      <script>$(document).ready(function(){load_(); console.log('load running')});</script>
   </head>
   <body id="dt_example">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="endpoints">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Nr.</th>
            <th>Java Class Name</th>
            <th>http Method</th>
            <th>URL</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            if (!$con) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
            mysqli_select_db($con,DB_NAME);
            $sql='SELECT * FROM url';
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              print $row['method'];
              switch ($row['http_method']) {
                            case "GET":
                                echo "<tr class='gradeA'>";
                                break;
                            case "PUT":
                                  echo "<tr class='gradeC'>";
                                break;
                            case "POST":
                                  echo "<tr class='gradeU'>";
                                break;
                            case "DELETE":
                                  echo "<tr class='gradeX'>";
                                break;
                            default:
                                  echo "<tr>";
                        }
              if($row['checked']){
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id=case name='case[]' value='" . $row['number']  . "' checked> </td>";
              } else {
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id=case name='case[]' value='" . $row['number']  . "'> </td>";

              }
                echo "<td align=center >" . $row['number'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align=center >" . $row['class_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['http_method'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td style='font-weight:bold'>" . $row['endpoint']  . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }

            if(isset($_POST['save'])){
              echo "<script>console.log(" . $checkboxes.length . ");</script>";

              $rows = $_POST['case'];
              foreach($rows as $row){

                $sql = "UPDATE url SET checked = 1 WHERE number = " . $case;
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
              }
            }


            mysqli_close($con);
            echo "</tbody></table>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='save' id='save' value='Save' />";
            ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

image:

[image: checkboxes]

EDIT:
Solved - here is the code:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
  echo "<script>console.log(" . $checkboxes.length . ");</script>";
  $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  if (!$con) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
  mysqli_select_db($con,DB_NAME);

  $rows = $_POST['case'];
  foreach($rows as $row){

    $sql = "UPDATE url SET checked = 1 WHERE number = " . $row;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      @import "demo_page.css";
      @import "header.ccss";
      @import "demo_table.css";
      @import "select.dataTables.min.css";
      @import "jquery.dataTables.min.css";
   </style>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="RowGroupingWithFixedColumn.js"></script>
   <script>$(document).ready(function(){load_(); console.log('load running')});</script>
</head>
<body id="dt_example">
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="endpoints">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Nr.</th>
         <th>Java Class Name</th>
         <th>http Method</th>
         <th>URL</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php
         $con = mysqli_connect('sql7.freemysqlhosting.net','sql7117068','GZqaZj69G9','sql7117068');
         if (!$con) {
             die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
         }
         mysqli_select_db($con,'sql7117068');
         $sql='SELECT * FROM url';
         $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
           print $row['method'];
           switch ($row['http_method']) {
                         case "GET":
                             echo "<tr class='gradeA'>";
                             break;
                         case "PUT":
                               echo "<tr class='gradeC'>";
                             break;
                         case "POST":
                               echo "<tr class='gradeU'>";
                             break;
                         case "DELETE":
                               echo "<tr class='gradeX'>";
                             break;
                         default:
                               echo "<tr>";
                     }
           if($row['checked']){
             echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id=case name='case[]' value='" . $row['number']  . "' checked> </td>";
           } else {
             echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id=case name='case[]' value='" . $row['number']  . "'> </td>";

           }
             echo "<td align=center >" . $row['number'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td align=center >" . $row['class_name'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['http_method'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td style='font-weight:bold'>" . $row['endpoint']  . "</td>";
             echo "</tr>";

         }




         mysqli_close($con);
         echo "</tbody></table>";
         echo "<input type='submit' name='save' id='save' value='Save' />";
         echo "</form>";
         ?>

</body>
</html>
```

PS: There may be many leaks and bad programming style in the code, but know that I'm not a PHP developer and it doesn't matter if there can be different attacks on my server. I only wanted to solve the problem and move on. Don't have time to stop at every point.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it doesnt matter if it can have injection or some other attacks, this is for internal use only. I only need to solve the problem, and thats all.

Comment: Sorry, that's a terrible excuse. "Internal use only" doesn't mean "a bunch of bugs are okay and if people put in an apostrophe it's perfectly fine that my code crashes hard." Do it properly and you won't have any problems. There are robots that crawl around looking for things to hack, and you don't want to be a victim of that. With a hole this big people can hijack your server and install software on it if they want.

Comment: What i meant with internal use is that the data's that are taken from database are not a secret, and if someone injects or hijacks my server and installs any server it could it wont matter at all, believe me. All i want is to make this work and don't mess with it a lot.

Comment: Look, just do it properly, it's not hard and it means you won't have to worry about escaping issues. If you insist on doing it this way, don't be surprised if you waste hours of time tracking down a silly single character mistake that could have been avoided if you did it properly in the first place. It's important to practice doing it correctly now so if this ever does end up being something that needs to be deployed to the public it's already good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use code below to check if a check box is checked or not. Then set some flags on some variables to insert data to to db accordingly.

```
//html
     <input type='checkbox' name='boxname' value='1' />
//php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['boxname'])
    {
        echo "check box is checked";
    }
?>
```

Comment: can you modify the whole html if you can(or someone other), i really tried everything but it doesn't work.

Comment: @nodeguy, I wouldn't be opposed to doing that for you, but for the fact your `<tbody>` is a total nightmare.

Comment: @amflare, php and html are not my daily work so i know i may have done alot of things wrong.
This is what is not working properly i think:
 if(isset($_POST['save'])){            
              $rows = $_POST['case'];
              foreach($rows as $row){
                $sql = "UPDATE url SET checked = 1 WHERE number = " . $case;
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
              }
            }

Comment: @nodeguy, I meant in terms of formatting. Now that it is formatted, I'll take a look.

Comment: @amflare, thanks for suggesting edit and for helping also. I solved the problem, now i have to take a look for getting unchecked value.

Comment: Uncheck value is just `!checkedValue`. Simple.